# What format is the coordinate of this geojson example

Tags: geojson

I have this geojson for bike paths and I can't seem to figure out what the coordinates represents. I was expecting longitude and latitude, but those doesn't seem to be it.

Here is an example:

```
"geometry":{  
      "type":"LineString",
      "coordinates":[  
         [  
            305049.6192401955,
            5061761.891977313
         ],
         [  
            305038.71863293805,
            5061778.694289856
         ]
      ]
   }
```

The source of data can be found here : [bike path data](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/pistes-cyclables)
Unfortunately, it is only in french, but the data is under geojson section then click on "Explorer/Aller a la ressource"

Any help is appreciated,

Cheers,

Comment: With format you mean the coordinate system? Have you tried Webmercator (EPSG:3857), the one that google and openstreetmap etc. are using?

Comment: basically i was expecting longitude and latitude in the coordinates .... but those doesn't seem to be it

Comment: What general area is the json supposed to show? Do you know what the source of the json is and is it possible to share it? As it is, it could be almost any projected coordinate reference system

Comment: I've edited the question to include the source of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data uses this spatial reference system: [EPSG:2950](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2950/), also known as: "NAD83(CSRS) / MTM zone 8". The units in this system is meters.

This information can be found at the top of your geojson file here:

```
"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2950"
```

The `crs` stands for coordinate reference system (*And for the trivia value, `EPSG` stands for "European Petroleum Survey Group"*).

This is likely confirmed by the shapefile from the same data source (based on your link), the .prj file states:

```
PROJCS["Ontario_MTM_Zone_8_east_of_75_degrees_W_NAD_83_datum"
```

The MTM refers to Modified Transverse Mercator. *If you want to easily convert this data (unproject it essentially) to WGS84 to get longitude latitude pairs, you could download the shapefile, unzip it, and add all files to [mapshaper.org](http://www.mapshaper.org/), open the console and enter `proj wgs84` and then export as a geosjon (or topojson).*

Comment: Can't say I do, I use mapshaper online for quick transforms, and only occasionally use command line GIS tools like GDAL.